# Modifying Image Source If Image Source Contains Sub-String

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am currently modifying a WordPress theme that happens to be a Divi child theme.

I am experiencing an issue where all images on new products are being replaced with a 400x400 thumbnail. I have disabled thumbnails via `Settings->Media` and setting everything to 0 and unchecking the option for thumbnails to be auto sized.

My issue is the thousands of images that have been uploaded by the customer are still showing as 400x400. I would like to resize these images by simply removing the "-400x400" substring from the image src via jQuery.

Below is the code that I have written do this; however, I receive no error but it doesn't correct my problem.

Is anyone aware of how I should be doing this or maybe why my code doesn't throw an error but doesn't function either?

```
var $imgs = $("img.wp-post-image");
$imgs.each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("src").indexOf("-400x400") >= 0) {
        var $newsrc = $(this).attr("src").replace("-400x400", "");
        $(this).attr("src", $newsrc);
        $(this).attr("width", "304");
        $(this).attr("height", "400");
    }
});
```

Comment: `function` has a typo in `$imgs.each(fucntion () {` is that in the real code as well? do you see any console errors?

Comment: Yes it was in the real code... I don't know how I didn't see that! Thanks, It still doesn't appear to have resolved the issue but I'm still not seeing any console errors regarding the script.

Comment: You may have to share some HTML along with your question to see how we can help.  It's impossible to troubleshoot with only a piece of the problem/solution

Comment: https://broadwayfashionista.com/product-category/formal-wear/tuxedos/

That is the website with the issue, If you notice there are two product images that are affected by the problem.

Comment: But you *are* receiving a console error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. You haven't enqueued jQuery.

Comment: I saw that too.  jQuery is not loaded correctly (or at all) - maybe you just need to put your custom.js file *after* jQuery loads

Comment: It should be noted that enqueueing scripts via `wp_enqueue_script()` would mitigate issues like these, as you can declare dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure your `custom.js` file loads ***after*** jquery is loaded.

Right now, your `custom.js` is trying to execute some code *before* jquery is loaded on the page

Also, there is a typo in `$imgs.each(fucntion () {`

It should read (of course) `function()`

Other than that, your code is working.  **[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4meawh1/)**

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the head section of your page, you'll notice custom.js is loaded before jquery.

```
<script src="https://broadwayfashionista.com/wp-content/themes/broadway-fashionista/js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


.........


<script type='text/javascript' src='https://broadwayfashionista.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3'></script>
```

try to invert the order

Comment: The code works fine, I simply needed to move the import down below a few things in my header.php file.... Woops. Any other day I would have figured this out but my brain is fried! Thanks for the assistance guys!